# Finding out the constant in p.d.f. with given mean?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Probability density function
$$f(x)=\alpha\ e^{-x^2-\beta\ x},\ -\infty<x<\infty$$
Also $E(X)=-\frac{1}{2}$
I tried solving it using respective formulas of total probability equal 1 and the formula of expected value of $X$ $i.e.$

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ xf(x)dx$$
Edit: I am unable to do the integration is there any other way to do that.

Comment: your formula for $E[X]$ is wrong it is $E[X]=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx $ . @Ab omm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the work I have.

\begin{align*}
E[X]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot \alpha\exp\{-x^2-\beta\ x\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot \alpha\exp\left\{-\left(x^2+\beta\ x+\frac{\beta^2}{4}-\frac{\beta^2}{4}\right)\right\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot \alpha\exp\left\{-\left[\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4}\right]\right\}\\
&=\alpha e^{\beta^2/4}\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+\beta/2}{1/\sqrt 2}\right)^2\right\}\tag 1\\
&=\alpha e^{\beta^2/4}\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)\left(-\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\alpha\beta\sqrt\pi e^{\beta^2/4}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I recognize that this is the expectation of a random variable with density of a $N(-\beta/2,1/2)$
and
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\alpha\ e^{-x^2-\beta\ x}\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \alpha\exp\{-x^2-\beta\ x\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \alpha\exp\left\{-\left(x^2+\beta\ x+\frac{\beta^2}{4}-\frac{\beta^2}{4}\right)\right\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \alpha\exp\left\{-\left[\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4}\right]\right\}\\
&=\alpha e^{\beta^2/4}\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+\beta/2}{1/\sqrt 2}\right)^2\right\}\tag 2\\
&=\alpha e^{\beta^2/4}\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt 2)\\
&=\alpha\sqrt{\pi} e^{\beta^2/4}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
where I recognize $(2)$ as the same density above.

It looks like this gives
$$\beta = 1$$
and
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}e^{-1/4}.$$

Comment: Thank you @probablyme you provided the whole solution.

Comment: @Abomm Well, this is what I think. I think it is a reasonable approach. I might have made a little mistake somewhere but I checked a couple of times. You can check that these values are actually correct. If you found this acceptable or correct, please click the check mark. Thanks.

Comment: It is absolutely correct but I want how you reached to this approach. I couldn't even think of that once,

Comment: @Abomm I just looked at it and I thought it looked _almost_ like a normal distribution. So I completed the square in the exponent and I proceeded like that. In my opinion, that is the trick to many of these kinds of problems, "make it look like something you already know".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$I=\int \alpha\ e^{-x^2-\beta\ x}\,dx$$ First, complete the square $$x^2+\beta x=(x+\frac \beta 2)^2-\frac{\beta^2}4$$ which makes $$I=\alpha \,e^{-\frac{\beta^2}4}\int e^{-(x+\frac \beta 2)^2}\,dx$$ Now, change variable $x+\frac \beta 2=y$ to get $$I=\alpha \,e^{-\frac{\beta^2}4}\int e^{-y^2}\,dy$$ The last integral is quite classical; express it as a function of $y$, go back to $x$ from the definition  and use bounds.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you @claude for providing hint.